# Has the behavior for DataAnnotations in asp.net mvc 3 changed?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, data-annotations, mvc-editor-templates

I have a Model with a property

```
[ReadOnly(true)]
public decimal BodyMassIndex { get; private set; }
```

In my View when I call

```
@Html.EditorForModel()
```

I still get a standard editable textbox for that property

Why is this? if the textbox is still editable whats the point of this DataAnnotation Attibute?

[Brad Wilson's post](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-2-modelmetadata.html)

Answer (score 4):

That is not a DataAnnotation attribute. Notice it's in the **System.ComponentModel** namespace. Data Annotations are in the **System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations** namespace.

However, this is a case where we could consider supporting it. But what exactly did you expect to happen and why do you want this?

Comment: Well, this example is for a PhysicalTest ViewModel. the form is supposed to display textboxes for Weight and Height. the BodyMassIndex is not supposed to be an input at all but I do want the user to know the BodyMassIndex (which is calculated from weight and height)...... I wanted to just use EditorForModel without having to create a custom EditorTemplate... imagine a form with two input text fields and then a BodyMAssIndex label that changes as soon as any of those two values change.

Comment: judging by your response I can tell Im not using this Attribute properly :s .Would you mind pointing out what the normal usage for this Attribute is?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK the ReadOnlyAttribute is for property of class. [From MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.readonlyattribute.aspx)

```
 Members that are marked with the ReadOnlyAttribute set to true or that do not have a Set method 
 cannot be changed. Members that do not have this attribute or that are marked with the 
 ReadOnlyAttribute set to false are read/write, and they can be changed. The default is No.
```

So you use this inside your classes to prevent modification to the properties. (at least the meaning I give to that attribute)

If you want a textbox readonly use something like that

```
 @Html.TextBox("MyText", "my text", new { @readonly="readonly" })
```

the @ first of readonly tell the compiler to bybass the reserved word

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x=> x.ModelProperty, new { @readonly="readonly"})
```

Comment: This would work but I want to use EditorForModel and defining a custom EditorTemplate just for this seems overkill.. also, Im still not sure what is the purpose and ordinary usage of the ReadOnlyAttribute

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand of your question and the comments on other answers, you simply want to display the BodyMassIndex, not have it as editable.

If this is the case, use `@Html.DisplayFor` rather than `@Html.EditorFor`.

Answer (score -1):

This works in Vs2013 C# with Bootstrap 3.

```
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PasswordHash, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-3" })
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PasswordHash, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @readonly="readonly" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PasswordHash, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
```