# Mark a field "Read Only" with Data Annotations

Tags: c#, .net, telerik, data-annotations

I am trying to make the `ID` field read only.  It is an Identity field in the DB so the user will not be setting it.  However they would like to see it.  What am I missing as the below, when assigned to a `DataForm` still allows that value to be Edited.

```
public class StatusChoice : BindableBase
{
    private int id;

    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Editable(false,AllowInitialValue = false)]
    public int ID
    {
        get { return id; }
        set
        {
            id = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Mark Property with ReadOnly attribute.

```
[ReadOnly(true)]
public decimal BodyMassIndex { get; private set; }
```

Follow below link for more
[Has the behavior for DataAnnotations in asp.net mvc 3 changed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7476405/has-the-behavior-for-dataannotations-in-asp-net-mvc-3-changed)

Answer (score 8):

You have two options in general based on situation.

`[Editable(false)]  or [ReadOnly(true)]`

Below are descriptions from MSDN

```
System.ComponentModel.ReadOnlyAttribute
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.readonlyattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Specifies whether the property this attribute is bound to is read-only or read/write. 
Members that are marked with the ReadOnlyAttribute set to true or that do not have a Set method cannot be changed. Members that do not have this attribute or that are marked with the ReadOnlyAttribute set to false are read/write, and they can be changed. The default is No.

```
System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.EditableAttribute
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.editableattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Indicates whether a data field is editable.

The presence of the EditableAttribute attribute on a data field indicates whether the user should be able to change the field's value.
This class neither enforces nor guarantees that a field is editable. The underlying data store might allow the field to be changed regardless of the presence of this attribute.