# make property as readonly using dataannotation attribute

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have property Name which I want to be readonly. So inside viewmodel I decorated this property with attribute readonly like

```
 [ReadOnly(true)]
 public string Name { get; set; }
```

and inside Edit view I have

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
```

and I'm still able to edit make changes inside textbox.

Should I use some css class to disable this textbox on the view side or this should be enough (if that is the case why this solutions does'nt work).

Comment: I know this is an old question but why is there a Validation message for Readonly = true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using editable attubute instead

```
[Editable(false)]
public string Name { get; set; }
```

Also see these q&a's

[Does ReadOnly(true) work with Html.EditorForModel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3510081/does-readonlytrue-work-with-html-editorformodel)

[ReadOnly attribute doesn't work in ASP.NET MVC Models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14995577/readonly-attribute-doesnt-work-in-asp-net-mvc-models)

Answer (score 1):

Have you thought to use @Html.DisplayFor instead of EditorFor which explicitly asks for an editor?

Answer (score 0):

Check my answer in [Mark a field "Read Only" with Data Annotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16455032/mark-a-field-read-only-with-data-annotations/37341564#37341564)

You have to use ReadOnly and Editable based on situation