# One way model update in Entity Framework for .Net core

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-1.0

I have a User table where I keep the profile information of the user along with some system generated columns and password.

I am using a model to query the database and send the result to the user. User modifies the profile information and send the request which I am using the same Model to deserialize. But I don't want the user to change those system generated fields.

What should I do?

Comment: I don't understand your question? If you don't want a user to modify some fields why are you exposing them to the user?

Comment: @DawidRutkowski They should be able to view the values - Read-Only fields.

Comment: Then simply disable the edition of those fields on the client side. You might also reset changes in those fields (or simply don't update them) on the server side when user will submit his changes.

Comment: @DawidRutkowskiThanks. This is precisely what i am doing right now but I thought there may be a better way to do by putting some annotations on model fields.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the Data Annotation attributes - try marking Property with ReadOnly attribute.

```
[ReadOnly(true)]
public decimal BodyMassIndex { get; private set; }
```

Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7476405/has-the-behavior-for-dataannotations-in-asp-net-mvc-3-changed) for more details.